# Nesting HTML5 <template> tag

Tags: html, templates, polymer, web-component, html5-template

**HTML5 rocks** does say that I can nest templates. But when I use them, like below, they don't render.

```
<template id ='#outer'>
  <ul>
    <template = '#inner'>
      <li>Stuff</li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</template>
```

However, the below works:

```
<template id ='#outer'>
  <p>hi</p>
    <template = '#inner'>
      <p>there</p>
    </template>
</template>
<div id="tDiv">

</div>      

    var outer = document.querySelector('#outer');
    var outerClone = outer.content.cloneNode(true);
    var check = outerClone.querySelector('template');
    var innerClone = check.content.cloneNode(true);
    var tDiv = document.querySelector('#temp');
    tDiv.appendChild(innerClone);
```

BUT this way, I am able to use either `innerClone` OR `outerClone` and I get a hi or there. Not hi there.

I am not able to get the real purpose of why templates are nested and not used independently. Doesn't nesting templates complicate stuff?

Comment: Is this question related to a Polymer web-component?

Comment: Just HTML5 <template> in general.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in Gotchas of using template in [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/#toc-gotcha) tutorial:

> Activating the outer template will not active inner templates. That is
>   to say, nested templates require that their children also be manually
>   activated.

Even if I ignore typo in `<template = '#inner'>` and assume that it is `<template id='inner'>`, I think you'll have to call `document.importNode(template.content, true)` individually on each template and then **use** it. In your example you are just appending outerClone to DOM which still contains inert inner template. You need to append activated inner template content to outer template to make both of them render.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2p9kbw4/1/) is one way of achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain a *hi there*, you have to create a full tree of cloned selectors (that is, `outerClone` and `innerClone`), and append it to the visible one (`tDiv`)
(templates are not visible)

```
<template id ='#outer'>
  <p>hi</p>
    <template id = '#inner'> // mind the *id* !!
      <p>there</p>
    </template>
</template>
<div id="tDiv">

</div>  

var outer = document.querySelector('#outer');
var outerClone = outer.content.cloneNode(true);
var check = outerClone.querySelector('#inner'); //mind #inner here
var innerClone = check.content.cloneNode(true);
outerClone.appendChild(innerClone);             //append inner to outer
var tDiv = document.querySelector('#temp');
tDiv.appendChild(outerClone);                   //append outer
```

Here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s9y3bax/) with the code running